# How to sort the Observable collection for a combo box

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have View source

```
<view:ValidationBaseView x:Class="test.View.test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:test.Resources"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:test.View"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:test.ViewModel"
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:testviewmodelx:Name="testview"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

Then i have my UI element
I have binded the Combobox with the ObservableCollection. but i know i need to have sorted value in the combo.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.Row="3" 
          x:Name="combo1" 
          Margin ="0" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=test}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="testpath"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ICollectionView`. Something like this:

```
// this is your existing collection of items
var items = ...;

var cv = new ListCollectionView(items);

// this will sort by the Foo property of each item
cv.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Foo"));
```

In your view, bind to the collection view instead of the original items.

Comment: i am trying this    <UserControl.DataContext>         <viewModel:testviewmodelx:Name="testview"/>     </UserControl.DataContext><CollectionViewSource> 
 </CollectionViewSource> but in my dockpanel i am getting error as "The property content is set more than once"  if you have any idea on this please help......